# Relay active low and ESP8266 GPIO pins

Tags: relay, pins, esp8266

I am using a ESP8266, specifically the ESP-12-E :

[image]

I have a Relay, SRD-05VDC-SL-C connected to GPIO pin 4.

It is wired in Normally Open(with my device to be powered wired into the top and middle pins counting from the top to the bottom of the picture below):

[image]

In my arduino code when I issue:

```
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
```

This seems to pull the pin LOW, which is the active state of the relay, powering it, which turns my device on before my control code has even had chance to run. I want to get the pin for output but keep it floating.

How do I setup my pin for output, but leave it 'floating' from code, or keep it high / floating, so that I have to explicitly issue:

```
digitalWrite(4, LOW);
```

Before low is sent to activate my relay?

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: use digitalWrite(4, HIGH); before pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

Comment: @Trevor_G Wait what. That's actually the answer. RenegadeAndy, have you tried *anything* at all?

Comment: @HarrySvensson no. I didnt expect the act of calling the pinMode() function to actually cause the pin to go to LOW.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy I do hope this is the last time you write "no" to that question. Why should we help you if you can't even try things on your own.

Comment: Sorry...without being informed how would I have known to try this? Researching GPIO and reading tutorials , which ALL say run pinMode **before** digitalWrite, how was I to know to try this? You have done little to nothing to help. @Trevor_G said all that was needed, you are not being helpful at all in your allegation.

Comment: FYI: Most of these devices have similar output stages where the latch that holds the output state is before the pin driver itself. If you write to it when the pin is input the state just sits there internal. BTW: some folks just toggle the pin direction with the internal state set rather than the pin state itself. Not a method I'm keen on though since they rely on the week pullup.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Yes, it never feels right adding one sentence answers...

Comment: GPIO4 is LOW during reset (and thus boot), so an active-low  relay will erroneously click on power-on if wired to GPIO4. use GPIO 3 or maybe 2 or 16. you also might want to set `pinMode(n, INPUT_PULLUP)` to lock it into floating until needed.

Comment: @danadavis how did you know this about which pins are low on boot etc? Whee is this docced?

Comment: RenegadeAndy, Thanks a lot, I could not find this solution anywhere, thank you so much, it solved my task, happiness to you,

Answer (score 2):

The answer thanks to Trevor_G was:

use digitalWrite(4, HIGH); before pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

Comment: Yes this really helped